# How to make a carousel but not with images, I want to use divs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to make a products carousel but I want to place div like this inside:

```html
<div class="box-wrapper ">
  <img src="Images/toy.jpg" />
  <div class="box-content">
    <a class="buy" href="javascript:void(0)"><span><i class="fa fa-cart-plus"></i></span></a>
    <div class="title">Toy</div>
    <div class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
    <span class="price">4.67$</span>
    <div class="footer">
      <ul>
        <li class="fa fa-star"></li>
        <li class="fa fa-star"></li>
        <li class="fa fa-star"></li>
        <li class="fa fa-star"></li>
        <li class="fa fa-star-o"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Maybe I will find an idea here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of carousel library/packages out there. But if you are just beginning coding you could look at doing a simple carousel yourself to get some idea of the concepts.

A very simple one can be found at: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_slideshow

Just put the code you want in in place of the imgs - in this simple case replace

```
<img src="img_snow_wide.jpg" style="width:100%">
```

for example with all the code you have given in your question. The whole thing will slide in and out just as an image would. Further ideas on e.g. an automatic slideshow are also given: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp

Or you could go straight to using others' code e.g. like bootstrap carousel plugin.

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan for editing the code in the question - now it is far better readable...